# Rails 3 / Google Analytics API / Garb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

Using garb (http://github.com/vigetlabs/garb) i need to fetch the same Map Overlay XML, like Google Analytics web interface export provides.
How it can be done?

```
Garb::Session.login("email@gmail.com", "pwd")
profile = Garb::Profile.all.first
profile.visits
```

+

```
class Exits
  extend Garb::Model

  metrics :pageviews, :visitors, :visits
  dimensions :request_uri
end
```

...works fine.

But i really cannot get what should i do next to get xml with geodata (city + lon/lat).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you in the right direction: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html#ga:latitude

These are dimensions, so you could get the number of pageviews or visits for a combination of lat/lng.

Rendering on a map is not something handled by Garb, just to be clear. Garb is only useful for exporting data from the API.

If you're using Garb with Rails and you're extending an active record object you should be able to call to_xml on that object. To use garb with AR, simply extend the class and set the instance class you want to use with Garb. https://github.com/vigetlabs/garb/wiki/With-an-ORM

Comment: Hi Thanatos - do you know of any good Rails app examples that use Garb to pull in Google data?